# arc length is a diffeomorphism on closed interval

Tags: calculus

Let $r:\, [a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb R^n$ be a regular curve, which means it is $C^1$ and $r'(t)\ne0\ \ \forall t\in[a,b]$, and its length is $\ell$.
Let \begin{align} s:\, [a,b]&\longrightarrow[0,\ell]
\\ t&\longmapsto s(t)=\intop_a^t\|r'(u)\|du \end{align}
be arc-length of $r$.

I have proved that $s$ is bijective on (a,b), continuous on $[a,b]$ and continuously differentiable on $(a,b)$. Hence, the inverse function $s^{-1}$ is defined on $(0,\ell)$ and continuously differentiable on $(0,\ell)$.

Now, how can I show that $s^{-1}$ also continuous on $[0,\ell]$ ?

May you give me some hints ? Thanks

Comment: In fact, $s$ is (right-) differentiable at $a$ and $s^{-1}$ is (right-) differentiable at $0$, hence continuous at $0$. BTW, you have the domain of $s^{-1}$ wrong both places.

Comment: Maybe interestingly, the inverse of a strictly increasing real-valued function _defined on an interval_ is automatically continuous; an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof is straightforward to construct from a sketch. (Continuity of the original function is not needed!)

Answer (score 0):

Arc-length is not less than Euclidean length. So $s^{-1}$ is [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), and therefore continuous.